# Sidekiq sporadically is getting nil for active records queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, clockwork

My project consists of a machine that has clockwork, that creates new models in the DB.

I also have in the model after_create creating a sidekiq task using perform_async.

My problem is this:
sporadically, when the sidekiq job starts, it queries for the model it was spawned for (if model X created a sidekiq job with parameter - X, sidekiq job queries for model with id X) - and it gets a nil!

how can that be? I am unable to trace what the problem is or what affects it.

after I retry the job it succeeds. - but it was made AFTER_CREATE so the model should already be committed to the DB.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered in the [FAQ wiki page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq). Use after_commit.

Comment: Can you add a link to this answer?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq